# How to connect H2O and Hive in a kerberized Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, h2o

I'm trying to connect H2O and kerberized Hive following this document: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html#connecting-to-hive-in-a-kerberized-hadoop-cluster

I'm sure that hiveHost, hivePrincipal, principal, keytab are all well configured.

Here is my environment:

- Hadoop 2.7
- Hive 2.2
- h2o-3.26.0.2-hdp2.6.zip and h2o-3.26.0.2-hdp3.0.zip (Tried both hdp2.6 and hdp3.0)

Following is the error message:

```
08-08 14:08:51.819 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #dex.html INFO: GET /flow/index.html, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:51.819 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #dex.html INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/index.html via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:51.870 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #flow.css INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/css/flow.css via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:51.933 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #/flow.js INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/js/flow.js via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.054 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #/h2o.png INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/img/h2o.png via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.083 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #ar.woff2 INFO: GET /flow/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.083 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #ar.woff2 INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2 via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.094 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #00.woff2 INFO: GET /flow/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.095 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #00.woff2 INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.101 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #tf.woff2 INFO: GET /flow/fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf.woff2, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.101 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #tf.woff2 INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf.woff2 via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.597 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #dex.html INFO: GET /flow/index.html, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.597 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #dex.html INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/index.html via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.654 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #ndpoints INFO: GET /3/Metadata/endpoints, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.859 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #notebook INFO: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/notebook, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.862 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #s/exists INFO: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/categories/environment/names/clips/exists, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.862 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #log.json INFO: GET /flow/help/catalog.json, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.862 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #log.json INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/help/catalog.json via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.863 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #/3/About INFO: GET /3/About, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.867 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #Builders INFO: GET /3/ModelBuilders, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.889 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #00.woff2 INFO: GET /flow/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:52.889 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #00.woff2 INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2 via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:52.891 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #flow.png INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/img/h2o-flow.png via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:53.035 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #ic.woff2 INFO: GET /flow/fonts/Lato-Italic.woff2, parms: {}
08-08 14:08:53.035 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #ic.woff2 INFO: Trying to load resource /flow/fonts/Lato-Italic.woff2 via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7e32c033
08-08 14:08:58.454 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #SQLTable INFO: POST /99/ImportSQLTable, parms: <hidden>
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR: java.lang.RuntimeException: SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hive.linktime.cloud:10000/default;auth=delegationToken: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR: Failed to connect and read from SQL database with connection_url: jdbc:hive2://hive.linktime.cloud:10000/default;auth=delegationToken
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.jdbc.SQLManager$SQLImportDriver.compute2(SQLManager.java:225)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1417)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hive.linktime.cloud:10000/default;auth=delegationToken: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:210)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.jdbc.SQLManager.getConnectionSafe(SQLManager.java:486)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.jdbc.SQLManager.access$000(SQLManager.java:13)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.jdbc.SQLManager$SQLImportDriver.compute2(SQLManager.java:134)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     ... 6 more
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2248)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:106)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:102)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:450)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:309)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:276)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:832)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:802)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:675)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Utils.getTokenStrForm(Utils.java:91)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.getClientDelegationToken(HiveConnection.java:539)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:464)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:226)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:183)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     ... 12 more
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at org.apache.hive.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2242)
08-08 14:08:58.472 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  FJ-1-15   ERRR:     ... 25 more
08-08 14:09:07.241 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #les/info INFO: GET /3/Logs/nodes/self/files/info, parms: {}
08-08 14:09:07.334 192.168.6.33:54321    15189  #les/info INFO: GET /3/Logs/nodes/192.168.6.33:54321/files/info, parms: {}
```

Did I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running h2o as a Hadoop job or standalone outside of Hadoop? delegationToken auth is only used when H2O is running as a Hadoop job.

If you you are running standalone you need to use kerberos authentication with something like jdbc:hive2://host:10000/default;principal=hive/host@REALM.COM.

If you are running as hadoop job via h2o_driver.jar then you need to make sure hive is on mapreduce classpath, either via libjars or via hadoop conf. More details are available in the docs.

Comment: I'm running H2O as a Hadoop job. According to H2O's document, Hadoop job is the only way to connect Kerberlized Hive. I tried standalone too, with kerberos authentication like you posted above, but no lucky.

Comment: if you are running as hadoop job you need to make sure hive is on mapreduce classpath, either via libjars or via hadoop conf

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked classpath, I think it's on the right place. I think the instance of `GroupMappingServiceProvider` is not expected, but I don't know how to setup a right instance.